# BigQuery - create table via UI from cloud storage results in integer error

Tags: unicode, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, byte-order-mark

I am trying to test out BigQuery but am getting stuck on creating a table from data stored in google cloud storage.  I am able to reduce the data down to just one value, but it is not making sense.

I have a text file I uploaded to google cloud storage with just one integer value in it, 177790884

I am trying to create a table via the BigQuery web UI, and go through the wizard.  When I get to the schema definition section, I enter...
ID:INTEGER

The load always fails with...
Errors:
File: 0 / Line:1 / Field:1: Invalid argument: 177790884 (error code: invalid)
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0. (error code: invalid)
Job ID  trusty-hangar-120519:job_LREZ5lA8QNdGoG2usU4Q1jeMvvU
Start Time  Jan 30, 2016, 12:43:31 AM
End Time    Jan 30, 2016, 12:43:34 AM
Destination Table   trusty-hangar-120519:.onevalue
Source Format   CSV
Allow Jagged Rows   true
Ignore Unknown Values   true
Source URI  gs:///onevalue.txt
Schema
ID: INTEGER

If I load with a schema of ID:STRING it works fine.  The number 177790884 is not larger than a 64 bit signed int, I am really unsure what is going on.
Thanks,
Craig

Comment: someting potentially fishy with your file. have you tried to create new file from scratch with just one number in it that you use in your test? it must work! it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file likely contains a UTF-8 byte order mark (3 "invisible" bytes at the beginning of the file that indicate the encoding) that can cause BigQuery's CSV parser to fail.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

I'd suggest Googling for a platform-specific method for view and remove the byte order mark. (A hex editor would do.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is definitely with file's encoding. I was able to reproduce error.
And then "fixed" it by saving "problematic" file as ANSI (just for test) and now it was loaded successfully.